# Why is Swift REPL throwing error in terminal after installation on on Debian

Tags: swift, server, debian, read-eval-print-loop

I have installed Swift on Debian 9.9 using the instructions here:

https://tecadmin.net/install-swift-debian-9-stretch/

I also installed `libicu-dev`, as per swift.org instructions for Ubuntu.

`swift --version` returns the correct version:

```
$ swift --version
Swift version 5.1.1 (swift-5.1.1-RELEASE)
Target: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
```

However, the REPL is giving me an error:

```
1> 1 + 2
error: Couldn't lookup symbols:
  swift_beginAccess
  swift_beginAccess
```

Searching the net brings up the error occurring in Swift Playgrounds, but I'm none the wiser as to why this is happening on the Debian terminal.